# mathematical max/min in neo4j cypher

Tags: math, neo4j, cypher

Follwing is a working query I wrote in cypher, using a `CASE` expression coupled with the `sign` mathematical function to workaround the apparent lack of a mathematical `min` method.

```
MATCH (a)-[ar:REL]->(b)<-[br:REL]-(c)
RETURN CASE sign(ar.integer-br.integer) WHEN 1 THEN sum(br.integer) ELSE sum(ar.integer) END AS integer
ORDER BY integer DESC
```

I needed to compare two numbers and take the lowest one (the same could be done for the highest), and then sum all the lowest results. This is the common math.min or math.max functions, not the min or max statistical aggregations.

Is there a better way to do it? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query might work for you.

```
MATCH (a)-[ar:REL]->(b)<-[br:REL]-(c)
WHERE ID(a) > ID(b)
RETURN b, SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN ar.integer > br.integer THEN br.integer
    ELSE ar.integer END) AS integer
ORDER BY integer DESC
```

The `WHERE` clause is used to prevent duplicate matches (otherwise your sums will have double their correct values). It also calculates the `SUM` for each `b` (the [aggregation](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/query-aggregation.html) "grouping key"), and then sorts the results in descending order. (If you did not aggregate with a grouping key, then there would be only a single sum, so sorting would not make any sense.)

Comment: Thanks. I had a grouping key, and some `WHERE` options which I forgot to paste. Sorry. Anyway putting the `CASE` inside `sum()` in `RETURN` clause is cleaner and correct as you said. Thank you very much!